# How can I persist notes after page refresh in note taking web application?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my project

[image: Screenshot of project]

```js
console.log("Welcome, This is my javascript code");


const form = {}

form.noteText = document.querySelector('#Text');
        form.addButton = document.querySelector('#AddButton');

        const notes = document.querySelector('#notes');

form.noteText.focus();


function showNote() {
             let text = form.noteText.value;
          let note = document.createElement('div');
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('span');

  note.classList.add('note');
                  
           note.innerHTML = `<div class='note-text'>${text}</div>`;
     deleteButton.classList.add('note-delete');
  deleteButton.innerHTML = '&times;';
 
  note.appendChild(deleteButton);
  notes.appendChild(note);

  form.noteText.value = '';
  form.noteText.focus();

  addListenerDeleteButton(deleteButton);
}

function addListenerDeleteButton(deleteButton) {
     deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
    deleteNote(e);
  });
}

function deleteNote(e) {
  let eventNote = e.target.parentNode;
         eventNote.parentNode.removeChild(eventNote);
}



form.addButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
        if (form.noteText.value != '') {
    showNote();
  }
})
```

```css
html, * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
  }
  
  body {
    font: 1.8rem/1.56 sans-serif;
    color: crimson;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 3.2rem 2.4rem;
    background: url(https://wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/black-wallpaper-30.jpg);
  }
  
  
  /* Form styles */
  textarea {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
  }
  
  textarea {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid crimson;
  }
  
 
  form button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2rem 1rem 0 0;
    height: 2rem;
  }
  
  #AddButton {
    width: 7rem;
    background-color: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    border: 0;
    transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  #AddButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #e600e6;
  }
  
  
  /* Note Styles */
  #notes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  
  .note {
    width: 24rem;
    height: 20rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    padding: 1.2rem 1.6rem;
    margin: 2.4rem 2.4rem 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0.9rem 1.2rem rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .note-text {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  
  .note::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.4rem 0.4rem;
  }
  
 
  
  .note span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    top: 0.2rem;
    right: 0.2rem;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .note span:hover {
    color: #333;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Note Taking App</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.12/typed.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style="color: crimson;">Note Taking App</h1>
  <form>
    <textarea name="Text" id="Text" cols="50" rows="8" maxlength="300"></textarea>
    
    <button id="AddButton">Add note</button>
  </form>

  <div id="notes"></div>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can any tell me about this? I need help to cover this code. I have tried too much but unfortunately, I can't solve this problem. ( Please anyone helps me and tell me how to do this ..?
And my code is here ... Are as follows:  I want to need this answer very quickly. I also told you again plz help me.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the community. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.
Ideally, you would like to add more information on what you're trying to accomplish in the question itself, not just a high-level description of your issue in the title. Also, ideally, you would like to ask something lower level than "how to persist notes", this is a very high-level question and shows little search before asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the notes after you refresh the page I would look at storing the notes in local storage.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

However, this isn't ideal for a production app and a more permanent storage solution would be to store it to a database using an api.